# EXTREMELY slow transfer speed

Tags: usb, performance, usb-flash-drive, flash, transfer-rate

I'm getting **VERY** slow transfer speeds with 3 different usb flash drives on different computers.
This are the aspects I consider relevant:

- USB 3.0 driver is installed
- USB 3.0 is enabled from BIOS
- Windows 8.1 as OS
- USB 2.0 flash drives
- USB legacy enabled and disabled (same result)
- File size range from 50 mb to 200 mb
- Flash drive formatted as FAT32 (16kB cluster)
- Flash drive plugged to 3.0 and 2.0 ports (same result)
- GA-Z170X-Gaming G1 motherboard
- Intel core i7 4790K 4.0Ghz processor
- Flash drive: Verbatim 32 gb 2.0

**Now the awful:
I'm getting 20 kB/s - 2mB/s Speeds. Most of the time 50kB/s**

What is going on here!?
I've tried EVERY SINGLE solution out there, and still. I need some external help here.

Another important aspect. All 3 of my flash drives were fine until I used them in my college lab computers. Those computers have Admin rights for engineers and I'm not sure if something such as a virus can damage an USB this way.

Comment: have you enabled the write cache in device manager?

Comment: Yes. Still, nothing.